# Inserting to linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I't trying to insert a new element in linked list. Why is my code not working properly?

Here I search for a pointer

```
Root* List::rod(int sk){
    for(Root *d = p; d != NULL; d = d->next){
        if(d->duom == sk){
            return d;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and here I try to insert a new element

```
//p - beginning of list g-end of list 

void List::Insert(Root *d){
    if(d != NULL){
        d->duom = 9000;
        if(d == p){
            d->next = p;
            p = d;
        }
        else if(d == g){
            g->next = d;
            g = d;
        }
        for(Mazgas *s = p; s->next != d; s = s->next){ 
            d->next = s->next;
            s->next = d;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main

```
List *S = new List;

S->Set(5);
S->Set(4);
S->Set(8);
S->Set(90);

S->Insert(S->rod(4));
```

And it's not working. I think that my **Insert** method is ok, but what's wrong with my **rod** method?

Comment: You are setting 'duom' to '9000'. ( d->duom = 9000 ) , you are using S->rod(4) which searches for '4'.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well I try to insert 9000 into the list.

Comment: For those who don't know Lithuanian, `duom` here means `data` and `Mazgas` means `Node`.

Comment: You are wrong, ``rod`` method is ok, but your ``Insert`` is quiet strange... I don't get it what are trying to do. I guess first part with ``Set`` method fill list, so you have list with ``[5, 4, 8, 90]``. Then you find node with data ``4`` and try to insert it. But if you do this you are will break links of list (because ``rod`` returns pointer). However I guess its ``not working`` because you never enters the loop, ``s->next != d`` is false (``d`` is second element in the list).